# Getting Illegal string offset 'uid'

Tags: php, sql

Please dont marked as DUPLICATE. I know there are a lot of posts with these error but none seem to be the same issue as mine.

What I am trying to do is to pull up data based on a uid/date from/date to. The UID is related to a login session where it represents the user's ID.

Here is my HTML code,

```
<input type="text" readonly name="uid" id="uid" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['myusername']; ?>" />
<input type="date" name="from" id="from" value="<?=$date['from']; ?>" />
<input type="date" name="to" id="to" value="<?=$date['to']; ?>" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

So from the code above, UID is a read-only and user can only select dates. So by default user can only get data from db with his own UID using different set of dates.

Here is my SQL code,

```
if($date['from'] !== NULL && $date['to'] !== NULL){
    // get table data
    $sql = 'SELECT `id`, `changeid`, `implemented_by`
    FROM `tracker` WHERE `implemented_by` = $uid `scheduled_start_date` BETWEEN :d1 AND :d2';
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid['uid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':d1', $date['from'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':d2', $date['to'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Now, every time I click on Submit button to retrieved the data I am getting this error,

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'uid' in C:\*\update_status_test.php on line 130`

`Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in C:\*\update_status_test.php on line 130`

Line 130 refers to below,

```
$stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid['uid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Can anyone help me understand why its giving such an error, I'm new to PHP and cant seem to comprehend the error.

Comment: How do you fill $uid var?

Comment: How about printing $_POST and checking it to see if any variables are getting.

Comment: Just before I connect to db, I have this - `$uid = $_POST['uid'];`

Comment: Why are you treating as array? Why not just $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR); ? Also, try to not use this POST value, get it from db.

Comment: After submit pls try $_POST and see whether variable is set or not

Comment: Use :uid instead of $uid in the sql.

Comment: There's no `:uid` placeholder in your query.

Comment: Thanks guys, learning new stuff in PHP/SQL. I was able to correct the error now. So mistake is I am treating it still as an array. But when I click on Submit, its giving new error - `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed code:

```
// get table data
// Fixes are in query text
// 1. replace $uid with :uid placeholder
// 2. add `AND` between conditions
$sql = 'SELECT `id`, `changeid`, `implemented_by`
FROM `tracker` WHERE `implemented_by` = :uid AND `scheduled_start_date` BETWEEN :d1 AND :d2';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
// as `$uid` is a simple string - pass it as is:
$stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':d1', $date['from'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':d2', $date['to'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you do this:

```
$uid = $_POST['uid'];
```

You can change this

```
$stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid['uid'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

into this

```
$stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thanks that seem to work. So my mistake was I am treating it still as an array. But when I click on submit now, its giving another error `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens`

Comment: Change $uid to :uid in the query.